# Ubuntu remote GUI X Error and QGLContext error

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu v18.04 with Cuda 10. Trying to open a gui from a remote centos machine gives me the following error.

```
-bash-4.2$ e2helixboxer.py --gui *.mrc
X Error: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation) 2
  Extension:    154 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 3 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x0
QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Cannot make invalid context current.
QGLContext::chooseContext(): Cannot share with invalid context
X Error: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation) 2
  Extension:    154 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 3 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x0
X Error: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation) 2
  Extension:    154 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 3 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x0
QGLTempContext: Unable to create GL context.
X Error: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation) 2
  Extension:    154 (Uknown extension)
  Minor opcode: 3 (Unknown request)
  Resource id:  0x0
QGLTempContext: Unable to create GL context.
None
```

The same command, however, runs fine from a centos machine 7-4 with Cuda 8.

Comment: Does https://praveen-palanisamy.github.io/blog/2017/02/15/Running-OpenGL-Applications-Remotely help?

Comment: Thanks. I think this really describes what I'm dealing with, but the post ends way too prematurely for me. When I run glxinfo |grep rendering on the local machine, the rendering is fine, but the remote one gives me X Error 154 (GLX). When I run ldconfig -p |grep libGL.so on either local or remote I get no output, just a new line in terminal. What's the "real" solution?